# why if,else condition inside of __init__ function does not work correctly? python 3

Tags: python

I'm a newcomer in python pure programming and I have created simply class "Human" and  would like to make some objects ones in the dictionary with all attributes of initial class function "--inti--", and problem is, I can not specify that type of expected format for "gender" parameter, and if-else condition inside of --init-- does not work correctly, I mean it always fills in the gender parameter as "Female" while I added, for example, one Man and one Woman there are two types of gender but it just adds gender = 'Female' for each object

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, age):
            self.name = name

            if  ('Famele' or 'female' or 'f' or 'F' in gender):
                    gender = "Female"
                    self.gender= gender

            elif ('Male' or 'male' or 'm' or 'M' in gender):
                    gender = "Male"
                    self.gender = gender

            self.age = age

lis_obj_name = []
def obj_creator():
    obj_number = int(input("how many object would you like to create? "))
    for i in range(obj_number):
            my_object = input('what is object name? ')
            lis_obj_name.append(my_object)




obj_creator()


my_objects = {objects: Human(input('your name '),input('male,or female(Plz write it) '),input('your 
age ')) for objects in lis_obj_name}
```

or for example with this if-else formate, it still doesn't work! :

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, age):
            self.name = name

            if  gender == 'Famele' or 'female' or 'f' or 'F':
                    gender = "Female"
                    self.gender= gender

            elif gender == 'Male' or 'male' or 'm' or 'M':
                    gender = "Male"
                    self.gender = gender

            self.age = age
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: I agree with @AMC your Boolean logic looks fine from a human perspective, but that is not how python actually reads that specific Boolean expression.

Comment: This question has the word "sexual" repeated too many times for comfort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the statement `if "Famele" or "female" or "f" or "F" in sexual`. This statement will always evaluate to `True` so `elif` block will never execute.

You can change the implementation of your `Human` class to this, which uses `in` operator to check the gender.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, sexual, age):
        self.name = name

        if sexual in ["Famele", "female", "f", "F"]:
            sexual = "Female"
            self.sexual = sexual

        elif sexual in ["Male", "male", "m", "M"]:

            sexual = "Male"
            self.sexual = sexual

        self.age = age
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value